# Data from previous VC (from API) cannot pass to another VC

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

The scenario should be, I am going to input *valid event code* to sign in in the App, If I entered valid event code, it should dispatch the **DashBoard** and event details should appear on it. The **DashBoard** was successfully dispatched but no event details appeared in the Labels and **Unable to insert COPY_SEND** appeared in the console. *event* and *validpincode* turns to nil when in reality it should have a value. [image: event and validpincode turns nil]. I am confuse where the issue was. in the _Unable to insert COPY_SEND_ or it does not fetch data from the API. I saw a lots of issues and solutions regarding COPY_SEND issue but I can find that helps my issue. Hope you can give me some of your time to help me. Thank you

**showEventDetails Function**

```
var validPincode: String!
var event: Event!


@IBOutlet weak var eventNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   configureAALoading()

    guard event != nil,
        validPincode != nil else {
            _ = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance).showError("No Event Details", subTitle: "There's no event details, please logout and try again")
            return
    }

    showEventDetails()
}
func showEventDetails() {

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.eventNameLabel.text =  "\(self.event.name.uppercased())"
            self.locationLabel.text =  "\(self.event.location.uppercased())"

            if let dateStringFromDate = getFormattedStringFromDate(date: (self.event.startDateTime), formatString: "MMMM dd, yyyy/ hh:mm a") {
            self.dateTimeLabel.text = dateStringFromDate
        } else {
            self.dateTimeLabel.text = "-"
        }
    } 
}
```

**validateEventPasscode from View Controller**

```
 func validateEventPasscode(){
    //Show Loading
    self.view.squareLoading.start(0.0)


    let api = APIService(APIKey: passcode)

    api.validatePasscode(passcode: passcode, successBlock: { (event) in
        // VALID PASSCODE AND NOT DELETED OR CLOSED EVENT

        self.event = event
        self.view.squareLoading.stop(0.0)

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showEventDashboard", sender: self)
        self.enteredEventCode.text = ""
```

**segue for Dashboard in ViewController going to DashBoardController**

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DashBoardViewController" {
        if let DashboardViewController = segue.destination as? DashBoardViewController {
            DashboardViewController.event = self.event
            DashboardViewController.validPincode = self.passcode
        }
    }
}
```

**APIService**

```
          func validatePasscode(passcode: String,
                  successBlock: @escaping (Event?) -> Void,
                  failureBlock: @escaping (Error) -> Void)
    {
       let passcodeURL = URL (string: "\(PASSCODE_CHECKER_URL)/\(passcode)")


Alamofire.request(passcodeURL!, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)

       if let error = response.error
       {
        failureBlock(error)
        return
    }

            if let passcodeJSON = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]],
                let passcodeObj = passcodeJSON.first {
                print(passcodeObj)
                let event = Event.init(JSON: passcodeObj);
                successBlock(event)
        }

        }

}
```

Comment: does ur app crashing

Comment: Where are you saving data in validPinCode and event??

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen It does not crash, It successfully dispatch my Dashboard but my dashboard is empty

Comment: can you show the configureaaloding func also

Comment: I guess you are pulling data from backend and displaying...?

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen my configureAALoading is for SCLAlertView

Comment: where you are setting values event and pincode, can you show that

Comment: I edited my question, I included the APIService, ValidateEventPasscode Function and segue.

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen _event_ and _validpincode_ is from my view controller, you can see my additional codes for references.

Comment: but you are not calling api  from viewdidload. that time both are null.

Comment: you passing data from previous view controller..? pincode and event

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen yes I'm passing data from previous VC to another

Comment: Check in `validatePasscode ` for `event`. Also, don't see any code whare you have assigned `self.passcode = passcode` in your so-called previous VC

Comment: @satish it's on the segue part of the code in previous VC. Should i create separate?